# Comparing A List of Dates

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

In my SQL WHERE caluse, I'm checking to see if a Report Date is in one of the list of dates which I am passing to my SQL stored procedure.

```
WHERE REPORT_RUN_DATE IN (@REPORT_RUN_DATES)
```

Let's say `@REPORT_RUN_DATE` IS EQUAL TO '11/09/2013'

That did not match (no records returned) so then, looking at the compare, I'm comparing a date field with a date that has already been converted to a string before being passed into the stored procedure. So then I tried.

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, REPORT_RUN_DATE, 101) IN (@REPORT_RUN_DATES)
```

Same issue. No match. No records returned. The reason why the dates are passed in as a string is there may be times I'll be passing in multiple dates e.g. `''11/09/2013','11/14/2013''` which is why I am using the IN clause. We do not store any time portions of the date so I'm only dealing with the date data type and not `datetime` or `smalldatetime`.

Most of examples of using the `IN` CLAUSE in T-SQL that I found had to do with `integers` or `strings` but not `dates`. I'm passing my parameters via ADO.NET using VB.Net 2012. Stepping through my code I know the values are passed correctly and that the values should return a result set.

Any advise on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Try using `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, REPORT_RUN_DATE, 101) IN (@REPORT_RUN_DATES)`.

Comment: You can't use a **single** comma seperated list in the `IN` clause. It must be **seperate** values

Comment: Are you sure there is no time portion saved in column `REPORT_RUN_DATE`? I. e. the time portion of all dates is 00:00:00 for all records?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just pass in multiple values like that.  You'll end up passing a string as a single value, then SQL will compare the date column *as a string* to the value passed in:

Here are some options:

- Use multiple date parameters (2?, 3?)
- Create a table-value parameter type for the stored procedure
- Call the sproc multiple times with different dates (loop in your VB code)
- Generate SQL in VB instead of calling a sproc (need to be cautious of SQL injection)
- reverse the comparison and use `LIKE`:

  ```
   WHERE @REPORT_RUN_DATES LIKE '%' + CONVERT(DATE, REPORT_RUN_DATE, 101) + '%'
  ```